# Hilbert's basis theorem for power series ring in many variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My teacher Proved that if R is Noetherian then $R[x]$ and $R[[x]]$ are Noetherian , how can i prove that again R is Noetherian if and only if $R[[x_1,...,x_n]]$ is Noetherian ,thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Yeap sorry , i edited

Comment: K, thanks, I got rid of the comment.

Comment: Also you might want to use that $R[x][y] = R[x,y]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

A quotient ring of a Noetherian ring is Noetherian.

Secondly, notice that if you take $R[[x,y]]$ and organize monomial terms with a common maximal power of $y$ and factor this power of $y$ out, you are looking at something in $(R[[x]])[[y]]$. You can use a similar idea with induction to show it for $n$ variables.

Comment: Yea i could prove it with that observations , at the end is just a corollary of the prove that  R[[x]] is noetherian